# Get specific value from a comma separated values in Oracle database

Tags: sql, jdbc, oracle10g, select-query

I have a table called `DUMMY_TAB` which has a column `COLOR` which contains comma separated values as `RED,BLUE,WHITE,GREEN,YELLOW`. Now i want to check whether multiple colors are present or not and i don't know the order in which values are stored.

I have used query like:

```
SELECT COLOR from DUMMY_TAB WHERE (COLOR LIKE '%GREEN%' OR COLOR LIKE '%VOILET%' OR COLOR LIKE '%ORANGE%');
```

but query is not returning anything. can i get any help here.

Comment: Aside from the fact that storing a comma-separated list in a column is horrible practice that violates basic normalization, if your table contained data as you describe, the query you posted would return that row.  If the query isn't returning a row, the data must not contain the string `GREEN`.  Perhaps the data in your table is lower case while you're searching for an upper-case value?

Comment: My row has upper case comma separated values same as of which ii have asked in my question. like GREEN,BLUE,YELLOW

Comment: If the data and the query are exactly as you show them, the query would return a row.  Show us a self-contained example the replicates your problem that we can run on our machines.  Otherwise, it's nearly impossible to debug what the problem might be

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a junction table.  SQL has this great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*.  Comma separated values are not the right method.

But, sometimes, you have no choice.  You are looking for:

```
where ',' || 'GREEN' || ',' like ',' || COLOR || ','
```

The use of delimiters ensures that you can find the value at the beginning and end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly violating normalization as highlighted by Justin Cave.

Also the best practice is to store them in columns of a table and not all in one.

I could not replicate your problem statement. See proof [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0bf6e/1/0)

```
create table temp (col varchar2(30));

insert into temp values('RED,BLUE,WHITE,GREEN,YELLOW');

SELECT * from temp WHERE col LIKE '%GREEN%';

COL
RED,BLUE,WHITE,GREEN,YELLOW
```